# Pandas - Find empty columns of the row and update in one column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've below code to read excel values

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'TestData.xlsx'))
print(df)
```

Excel data is

```
    Employee ID First Name Last Name    Contact Technology  Comment
0            1   KARTHICK      RAJU  9500012345       .NET      
1            2       TEST            9840112345       JAVA      
2            3                 TEST  9145612345        AWS      
3            4                       9123498765     Python      
4            5       TEST      TEST  9156478965
```

Below code returns `True` if any cell holds `empty value`

```
print(df.isna())
```

like below

```
   Employee ID  First Name  Last Name  Contact  Technology  Comment
0        False       False      False    False       False     True
1        False       False       True    False       False     True
2        False        True      False    False       False     True
3        False        True       True    False       False     True
4        False       False      False    False        True     True
```

I want to add the comment for each row like below

```
Comment

Last Name is empty
First Name is empty
First Name and Last Name are empty
Technology is empty
```

One way of doing is iterating over each row to find the empty index and based on the index, `comments` can be updated.

If the table has huge data, iteration may not be a good idea

Is there a way to achieve this in more pythonic way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify solution and instaed `is` and `are` use `-`, use matrix multiplication [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) with boolean mask and columns with new value, last remove separator by [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html):

```
#if column exist
df = df.drop('Comment', axis=1)

df['Comment'] = df.isna().dot(df.columns + '-empty, ').str.rstrip(', ')
print (df)
   Employee ID First Name Last Name     Contact Technology  \
0            1   KARTHICK      RAJU  9500012345       .NET   
1            2       TEST       NaN  9840112345       JAVA   
2            3        NaN      TEST  9145612345        AWS   
3            4        NaN       NaN  9123498765     Python   
4            5       TEST      TEST  9156478965        NaN   

                             Comment  
0                                     
1                    Last Name-empty  
2                   First Name-empty  
3  First Name-empty, Last Name-empty  
4                   Technology-empty
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks! +50 :-)